# PostgreSql docker-compose Permissions should be u=rwx (0700) or u=rwx,g=rx (0750)

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose

I have an error after starting the container:

```
PostgreSQL Database directory appears to contain a database; Skipping initialization
2023-10-10T02:18:54.886882600Z 
2023-10-10T02:18:54.899928500Z 2023-10-10 02:18:54.899 UTC [1] FATAL:  data directory "/var/lib/postgresql/data" has invalid permissions
2023-10-10T02:18:54.899974300Z 2023-10-10 02:18:54.899 UTC [1] DETAIL:  Permissions should be u=rwx (0700) or u=rwx,g=rx (0750).
```

My docker-compose container

```
  postgres:
    container_name: "postgres-"
    image: postgres:16.0
    restart: unless-stopped
    command: postgres -c max_connections=200
    volumes:
      - ./runtime/data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
      - ./runtime/postgres/socket:/var/run/postgresql
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
      - POSTGRES_DB=postgres
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
...
...
volumes:
  postgres-tl:
```

Everything runs well on WSL, even on non-Linux, but not on windows

Comment: The error message is clear, isn't it?

Comment: You declare a named volume in the setup, but don't use it in the actual container.  Would replacing the pair of bind mounts with a single mount of the named volume `volumes: [postgres-tl:/var/lib/postgresql/data]` help?